# iOS - Set the code to 4 UIImageViews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app there are 4 UIButtons, which all are connected to 4 UIAlerView so when a button are pressed an UIAlertView should pop up. This works fine with all UIButtons. One of the options in the UIAlertView should open photo library so the user can change the picture of 4 UIImageView´s, which are connected to each UIButton.
the problem is that when I Choose a picture from any from the UIButtons the photo applies to just one ImageView, the fourth.
Here is my code for the UIAlertView:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

//UIAlertView´s in the UIButtons setup
if (alertView.tag == 1) { //button1
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        NSLog(@"Done");
    }
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
        NSLog(@"Number");
    }
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex+1) {

        imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];   //I think its this part which are wrong
        [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
if (alertView.tag == 2) { //button2
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        NSLog(@"Done");
    }
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
        NSLog(@"Number");
    }
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex+1) {

        imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];   //I think its this part which are wrong
        [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
 if (alertView.tag == 3)
 {
     if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
         NSLog(@"Done");
     }
     if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex){
         NSLog(@"Number");
     }
     if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex+1){
         imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];   //I think its this part which are wrong
         [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
         [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
         [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
     }

 }
if (alertView.tag == 4);
{
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex){
        NSLog(@"Done");
    }
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex){
        NSLog(@"phone number");
    }
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex+1){
        imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

}




@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code is extremely redundant. It is 4 times exactly the same, save for the value of the tag. Use a **variable** and write the code only once!

Second, the code you quote has nothing to do with the problem. Assuming that you also gave the image views the same tags as the buttons / alerts, you need to assign the image to the correct image view in the **image picker controller callback**. This is logical because you have to know which image is picked before assigning the image. Use

```
imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
```

You could keep a variable `int lastButtonTag` so you know which button was last pressed.

Comment: I'm pretty new in programming so can you give some examples please ?

Comment: No, sorry. This is not the right forum to learn programming from scratch. Please do some tutorials, take a computer course or such similar things. First step to good citizenship in this forum is to mark the answer above with a checkmark.